# SQL FOREACH LOOP Syntax

Tags: sql, foreach

Ok from what I can tell in my searches most of the people answering a question related to this is against `foreach` loops in sql.
But I actually need to do a `foreach` loop. my problem is that i can't for the life of me remember the syntax for doing it and like I said nobody seems to want to give up the layout of it, so now I am here asking for any help at all.

Maybe its not necessary for a foreach loop, but its the best possible way i can see.

I need to do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement on a table that contains 20120 signals for about 800 units in a 1 month time period. So i cant be certain about any specific amount of signals from each unit. Now that's why I need to do the count. I need to get accurate amount of signals for each unit, and doing it one unit number at a time is not an option. So I need to work through each unitID and get a count of the amount of signals passed by that unit in a certain time period.

So basically I need a way to run through all the unitID's and get a count for each individual unitID without giving a unitID to look for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
If you can not think of another way than a `foreach` loop too do this and you have the syntax for the `foreach` loop. Please just post it?? This is rather urgent

Comment: You don't need a FOREACH loop for this. You can do this using a set-based approach. <str>I'll post</str>RichardTheKiwi has posted what a "typical" query would look like, but if you post your schema and some example data, I can give you a more exact answer.

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you need a loop.  What you have described is a bread and butter set-based GROUP BY scenario.

```
select unitID, count(*) countSignals
from   signal_table
group by unitID
order by unitID
```

Comment: Yep - that's what I was about to post :)

Comment: Great thanks that worked brilliantly. Could i maybe ask for the syntax of a foreach loop in sql. I know it's not something you would use a lot but its just for my own peace of mind to have it either way. You never know when you might actually need it and I would like to have it for when that might happen.